# Маленькие модальные окна на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Посоветуйте маленькие модальные окна на `jQuery`.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Маленькое))) что то типа такое окно)))

```
$('елемент').click(function(e) {
$('#conteiner').css({
'margin':'auto',
'width':'500px',
'height':'100%'
'background':'#fff'
})
$('body').append('<div id="fade"><div id="conteiner"></div></div>');
$('#fade').css({
'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'
'width':'100%',
'height':'100%',
'background':'#000'
}).fadeIn();
});
```